# Eclipse (SWT composite): How to run and where is build?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am new to Eclipse and Java programming having mainly worked with Microsoft Visual Studio.

I installed Eclipse (Kepler 4.3) with no issues along with WindowsBuilder and SWT.

I created a new project adding in references to SWT, both WindowsBuilder JARS, and resty. Into the project, I created a new package and selected a SWT composite. I gave appropriate names.

The GUI designer came up with no issues. I added in a couple of controls. The idea is to create a hello world application, display that application, and build it. Eclipse has automatically build checked.

Okay, the IDE in designer view shows the GUI of my Hello World application and the source view the source, so no problems there.

I press Run, and the first time I had to select a run configuration, which I selected EclipseStarter. There was not many options. I click on run and nothing happens.

If I go to the project's bin package folder, I see a file with a ".class" extension.

1. Why does pressing Run|Run (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) do nothingness? There is a brief hour glass showing, but then nothing after that.
2. How do I launch the application from within Eclipse?
3. Is the generated ".class" file the correct runtime? I double click on that and Windows does not know what to do with it?

The end platform will be CentOS, but Java as I understand things, should be platform independent, so my Hello World application should run on my Windows 7 Pro box just as nicely. (I did not try CentOS yet) as I want to see it work on my desktop and know what file to copy over.

Answer (score 0):

I think you selected the wrong option EclipseStarter. 
Try running it as a Standalone Java Application. 
It is a Standalone Java Application that you're building, right?
(I mean, the analogue of a Windows Forms App in .NET)

1. I guess because you selected the wrong type.

2. Ctrl+F11 is for Running it, F11 only is for Debugging it.

3. The class file has to be run by a JVM, Windows cannot run it directly, 
it is not anything like a native executable or like a .NET assembly 
(which Windows 7 knows how to run). But as you're using Eclipse you 
already have a JVM.

Comment: Yes, I want to build a stand-alone Java application. My thought is to build the equivalent of an Windows executable, just a cross-platform Java application. The first time that I selected to run, I was asked to configure the run. I did not know what to select. I am also not sure how to run a class. I can try whatever on Monday, when I get back to the PC. If I delete the current run configuration, what run configuration do I select to run the application and how can I run the application outside of the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is multi-fold.

1. I had to delete Eclipse and install the 32-bit version of everything. That simplified life, as 64-bit caused issues running.
2. Create a new package
3. From the toolbar, select "Create new visual classes" drop down. Select "SWT" --> "Application windows".
4. Create the application window
5. Press the play button, 8th icon having selected the package first.

That enabled to run my Hello World on Windows. The output is a .java.

I still have a problem running from the command line, but that is a different issue.

Summary: My main issue was creating a SWT application window first and that I should have 32-bit for everything.